# While clicking the button in one of the applications I am working on, in android studio, the app crashes

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application called connect3 which is basically a tic tac toe game. After the game gets completed I have included a "Play Again!" button which will allow the user to play the game again. But after clicking the button, the application crashes.

Here is my Java file:

```
package com.example.connect3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.GridLayout; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// 0: yellow, 1: red, 2: empty

int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};
int activePlayer = 0;

boolean gameActive = true;

public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1500);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;

        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;

        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(300);

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                //someone has won!

                gameActive = false;

                String winner = "";

                if (activePlayer == 1) {

                    winner = "Yellow";

                } else {

                    winner = "Red";
                }

                Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);

                TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

                winnerTextView.setText(winner + " has won!");

                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    }
}

public void playAgain(View view) {

    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);

    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for (int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

        counter.setImageDrawable(null);

    }

    for (int i=0; i<gameState.length; i++) {

        gameState[i] = 2;

    }

    activePlayer = 0;

    gameActive = true;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="409dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:tag="7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8" />

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/winnerTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="179dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="174dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:onClick="playAgain"
    android:text="Play Again!"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/winnerTextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

LogCat File:

> 2023-06-05 18:24:54.311 12409-12409 AndroidRuntime
> com.example.connect3                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.connect3, PID: 12409
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
> android:onClick
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
> at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
> at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.GridLayout
> at com.example.connect3.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:94)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
> at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Answer (score 0):

The problem cause probably is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout at com.example.connect3.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:94)`

I think you imported the wrong GridLayout because `findViewById(R.id.gridLayout)` is returning `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout` and not `android.widget.GridLayout`

If you look inside the XML file the grid is also defined as `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`, so you could try changing the import at the top of your Java file.

Answer (score 0):

The log says that the app can't make the link between your button and your listener. It's better to declare your listener in your Java file.
Something like that:

```
Button playAgain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
playAgain.addClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  // here, the content of playAgain() method
});
```